# Variable is set but not displaying in an echo statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I want to display the logged-in member’s username inside my nav tag, but after running it doesn’t display anything. I have checked the variables `$_SESSION['u_user']= $row['username'];` and it displays the correct username. Below is the code. Please help me fix it.

```
   <?php 
   if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
       echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php $_SESSION["u_user"]; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="login">DashBoard</a></li>
                <li><a href="includes/logout.php" >Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="login.php">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opening and closing PHP tags (`<?php` and `?>`) inside an `echo` statement. That’s not how it works. The browser is treating that as an HTML tag and therefore hiding the information in between. You should have this code instead:

```
echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">' . $_SESSION["u_user"] . '<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="login">DashBoard</a></li>
            <li><a href="includes/logout.php" >Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>';
```

Please note that doing this this way is a bad idea. If you are not *extremely* careful in validating usernames, you will be vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks. You should escape the username output (as in `htmlentities($_SESSION["u_user"]`) or, even better, use a template engine that handles these things for you.